# How to scale an arc?

Tags: c++, algorithm, turbo-c++

I have to make a program that scales an arc (which in this case looks like a C). I'm using Turbo C++(ikr?) and the inbuilt function of arc is *void arc(int x, int y, int stangle, int endangle, int radius)*.
When the *x:y* scaling is 1:1 then there's no problem. I could just multiply the  radius. But what can I do when the *x:y scaling* is not 1:1? What values should I add to the other parameters to make it perfectly scaled?

Comment: Look up the `ellipse()` function.

Comment: @Peter it could be used but the question remains **How to scale it?**

Comment: `ellipse()` would probably have two axis parameter so scale would not be a problem (I am not 100% sure)

Comment: Did you even bother to look it up?  `ellipse()` has two parameters for `xradius` and `yradius`.   If they are equal, it works like `arc()`.   Guess what happens if they are not equal.

Comment: @Peter Yeah, I didn't take a close look. Sorry. Thanks for the help. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. If non-uniform scale is applied to the circular arc, it's not an arc anymore.

Comment: Any ideas how to make a big C on Turbo C++ which can be scaled?